# Redirect url typed in browser to a different one, without affecting typed url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect user when type

```
http://example.com/event
```

to

```
http://example.com/?page_id=345
```

I tryed many codes in htaccess but non of them worked.
All of them page redirects, but browser url also change to new one.

Comment: redirect, but change the url of address bar to new one.

Comment: If I type http://example.com/event on browser, I will redirect to http://example.com/?page_id=345 page. But the browser url is not http://example.com/event. I need to redirect to http://example.com/?page_id=345, but I need the browser url display as http://example.com/event

Answer (score 1):

This should work :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^event/?$ ?page_id=345 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Comment: This also redirect the page and browser url will be changed to new one. Why is that? Is it any other problem?

Comment: Yes, may be browser's cache. Try crearing your browser cache and Try again.